# SharedPreferences Not Working as I would expect

Tags: android, properties, sharedpreferences

I am running into an issue with Shared preferences.  It isn't working as I expected.  Upon login of my application I store an id (google id) in the shared preferences.  On a subsequent activity (about 3 activities later) I attempt to retrieve the id but it is null.  In case it is important, I am attempting to retreive the shared preferences in a onClickListener (from a button).  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

How I am setting it:

```
    public void setLoginPreferences(String id){

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.ID_KEY_NAME, id);
    editor.commit();
}
```

How I am attempting to get it:

```
    //setup clickListener for Sumbit Comment
    Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitComment);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //myContext is a global variable set on the onCreate of the activity
            SharedPreferences prefs = myContext.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String userId = prefs.getString(Constants.ID_KEY_NAME, null);   
            SetConcertCommentAsynchWebservice scca = new SetConcertCommentAsynchWebservice(myContext,concertId,userId,Float.toString(soundRatingBar.getRating()),Float.toString(showRatingBar.getRating()),userSubmittedComments.getText().toString()); 
        }});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to use `context.getSharedPreferences()` instead of `context.getPreferences()`, if you want to access them somewhere else.